# Cashbook report in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have to create a Crystal Report which will print the below output for a date range.

```
Date : dd-mm-yyyy

    Description | Credit | Debit 

    abc          2000       00
    xyz           00        1000
Closing Balance: xxxx
Opening Balance: xxxx
Total Credit Till: Date  xxxx Rs
Total Debit Till:  Date  xxxx  Rs
```

Query I have tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         BUSI_DATE AS busiDate, PARTICULARS AS "desc", 
         AMOUNT, 'DR' AS transectionType 
     FROM 
         TRANSECTION_OUT 
     WHERE 
         BUSI_DATE BETWEEN @S_DATE AND @E_DATE

     UNION ALL

     SELECT 
         BUSI_DATE AS busiDate, PARTICULARS AS particular, 
         AMOUNT, 'CR' AS transectionType 
     FROM 
         TRANSECTION_IN 
     WHERE 
         BUSI_DATE BETWEEN @S_DATE AND @E_DATE) T 
ORDER BY 
    T.busiDate
```

The problem is we have to print one day records in one page. I not much experienced with Crystal Reports - please help, how we can achieve this in Crystal Reports windows application?

Comment: Are you searching help on your SQL statement or on how do operate Crystal? In the latter case this question is too big to answer here.

Comment: I was looking for crystal part.

Comment: I'm afraid you should take a look at the documentation for that. Or you come up with a specific question here.

Comment: Alex can you help with "The problem is we have to print one day records in one page" this statement only. I can print the data of daterange but don't know how to split that for one day one page.

Comment: You have to group the query by day. I‘ll try to build an answer tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry but the download is broken currently so I'm not able to install CR currently. I left an incident at SAP and wait now.

Comment: Please check if this version works for you. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bc77fTM5prUiimSFDAd1LxsahzFqnQce